# JavaFX listview init() method

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am working with JavaFx to try and load a listView of Book titles. My main application switches between two views, a list of book titles(what im working on) and a detailed view for each book. I have tried to implement the listView as such:

```
public class BookListController implements Initializable, MyController{  
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> list;
    private List<Book> books;

    public void populateList() {
        //list.getItems().addAll("Book 1", "Book 2", "Book 3", "Book 4");
        books = BookTableGateway.getInstance().getBooks();
        for(Book b : books) {
            list.getItems().add(b.getTitle());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        populateList();

    }
```

I used `list.getItems().addAll("Book 1", "Book 2", "Book 3", "Book 4");` to test out my code and this worked fine. My problem comes from changing this to get data from a database(I can get the data succesfully). The list view  will load succesfully the first time I open it. However, if I try to switch between views that titles no longer get loaded into the list, after the first time.

Since my call to load this view is `controller = new BookListController();` shouldn't init() be called each time, which would load the list view?

Comment: If by `init()` you mean the `initialize` method, that method is only called during the invocation of `FXMLLoader.load` (any of the overloads).

Comment: @Slaw, oh ok. It seem I do have a call to FXMLoader everytime I switch to this view, which I'm assuming was what was loading `"Book 1", "Book 2", "Book 3", "Book 4"`. Even though I've changed `populate()` a bit, shouldn't it still continue to successfuly load the listview like it did before?

Comment: Simply creating an instance of the controller does nothing except invoke the constructor. All the FXML related stuff is only handled/initialized by an `FXMLLoader`, via a call to `load`. And if your FXML file uses `fx:controller` then instantiating your own controller instance is unnecessary/wrong as the `FXMLLoader` instantiates and uses it's own instance; you can get that instance via `FXMLLoader.getController` (_after invoking `load`_).